# Problema ao retornar os models do Entity: "The entity or complex type ... cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

Estou tentando retornar uma lista dos objetos gerados pelo DataBase First do Entity Framework mas me aparece esse erro:

> The entity or complex type 'leaosites04Model.TB_LEMBRETES' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Estou tentando de alguma forma não criar uma classe para cada tipo diferente de consulta que faço com colunas diferentes no EF... 
O método está assim:

```
public List<TB_LEMBRETES> getLembretes(int? situacao)
{
    try
    {
        using (dbEmpEntities db = new dbEmpEntities())
        {
            List<TB_LEMBRETES> result = 
                (from l in db.TB_LEMBRETES
                 join c in db.TB_CLIENTE on l.TB_CLIENTE.id_cliente equals c.id_cliente
                 where l.situacao == 0
                 select new TB_LEMBRETES
                 {
                    dt_lembrete = l.dt_lembrete,
                    obs = l.obs,
                    TB_CLIENTE = new TB_CLIENTE() { id_cliente = c.id_cliente, nome = c.nome }
                 }).ToList();

            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

TB_LEMBRETE e o TB_CLIENTE são models, dentro do Model1.edmx (dentro do Model1.tt), que foram gerados pelo Entity no momento do Database First.

Já vi na net em alguns locais que isso não é possível, mas não entendi porque!

Segue abaixo os models:

```
[Table("leaosites04.TB_LEMBRETES")]
public partial class TB_LEMBRETES
{
    [Key]
    public int id_lembrete { get; set; }

    public int? id_cliente { get; set; }

    public DateTime? dt_lembrete { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    [StringLength(65535)]
    public string obs { get; set; }

    public virtual TB_CLIENTE TB_CLIENTE { get; set; }
}


[Table("leaosites04.TB_CLIENTE")]
public partial class TB_CLIENTE
{
 public TB_CLIENTE()
 {
     TB_LEMBRETES = new HashSet<TB_LEMBRETES>();
     TB_TELEFONES = new HashSet<TB_TELEFONES>();
 }

 [Key]
 public int id_cliente { get; set; }

 [Required]
 [StringLength(100)]
 public string nome { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<TB_LEMBRETES> TB_LEMBRETES { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução sugerida pelo Harry Potter, é realmente a mais prática e mais sugerida, porém, complementando a forma que começou a fazer, deveria ficar algo assim:

```
public List<TB_LEMBRETES> getLembretes(int? situacao)
{
    try
    {
        using (dbEmpEntities db = new dbEmpEntities())
        {
            var resultTipoAnonimo = 
                (from l in db.TB_LEMBRETES
                 join c in db.TB_CLIENTE on l.TB_CLIENTE.id_cliente equals c.id_cliente
                 where l.situacao == 0
                 select new 
                 {
                    dt_lembrete = l.dt_lembrete,
                    obs = l.obs,
                    id_cliente = c.id_cliente, 
                    nome = c.nome
                 }).ToList();

            List<TB_LEMBRETES> result =
                resultTipoAnonimo.Select(r => new TB_LEMBRETES()
                {
                    dt_lembrete = r.dt_lembrete,
                    obs = r.obs,
                    TB_CLIENTE = new TB_CLIENTE() { id_cliente = r.id_cliente, nome = r.nome }
                }).ToList();

            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, você recupera uma lista de tipo anônimo e converte depois para o seu tipo desejado.

Acredito que somente em casos onde se queira uma quantidade mínima de colunas dentre muitas existentes, ou então em caso de ter coluna com grande volume de dados na mesma tabela, como um blob, por exemplo, é que seria recomendado usar dessa última forma, assim pouparia de buscar por um volume tão maior de dados que nem se quer faria uso.

Comment: Muito obrigado Luiz, isso me ajudou muito! Resolveu meu problema =D
Eu não tinha pensado em dar um novo Select pq isso gera um novo processo pro sistema...
Ou esse select possui algum tipo de performance que não demora mto?
Me preocupo quando eu tiver muuuitos dados, são praticamente um select demorado no banco e mais outro passando pelos mesmos dados

Comment: @Luiz perfeito, obrigado pelos créditos, são poucos aqui que reconhecem.

Comment: Reynaldo, claro que esse novo select terá algum custo, mas muito longe de ser algo crítico, pois os dados estarão todos em memória já, apenas criará uma lista de objetos com dados já disponíveis, não fará uma nova pesquisa em banco.

Que isso @HarryPotter, estamos aqui pra somar!